# Print structure in Lisp

Tags: printing, lisp

I want to be able to print the variable of a structure when I instantiate it, in order to see what is going on.  I have profusely googled this idea and cannot find anything concrete.

So for instance:

```
(setf object-name
      (make-the-object :obj-var value
                       :obj-var1 value))
```

Could this become something like this:

```
(setf object-name
      (make-the-object :obj-var value
                       :obj-var1 value
                       :(print obj-var1)))
```

so that the variable is printed on instantiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(setf object-name (print (make-the-object :obj-var value :obj-var value)))
```

Comment: this worked...i should done this originally but i was nervous because I didnt kno what print returned...thanks!

Comment: Welcome. In Lisp (unlike Clojure or Python, for example) print always returns the object, passed to it, which is very handy for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dedicated object-maker function, you can always just trace that function.